# Rserve - Eclipse & Java

Tags: java, r, rserve

Hi I am setting up rserve based on the instructions on this website. 
http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rserve/

However in eclipse I am getting an error when using 'eval'

```
             double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles();
```

error - 'The method eval(String) is undefined for the type RConnection'

The JARS have been correctly loaded into the build path and rserve is running, however I cannot figure out why only the eval function is causing an issue.

In addition to this the import of ...

```
   import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
```

causes an error - 'The import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection conflicts with a type defined in the same file'

does anyone have any idea why this is the case? Thanks

all imports :

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;




 public class RConnection {
public int[] mean(String a[]) {

    setupR();        

    return null;
}

public void setupR(){

    try {

        /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running
         * on default port 6311
         */

        RConnection c = new RConnection();// make a new local connection on default port (6311)

        double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles();
        org.rosuda.REngine.REXP x0 = c.eval("R.version.string");
        System.out.println(x0.asString());

    } catch (RserveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all the `import` statements from that file? You seem to import something that may also have an RConnection class.

Comment: Hi I put all the updated imports in my question.

Comment: Those imports look OK. Do you have a `RConnection` type defined in that file?

Comment: I will paste the whole class in (its quite small)

Comment: It is now updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;` you are tying to make `RConnection` known in the local namespace.
However, you already defined a class called `RConnection` locally.

Please rename your class `RConnection`, and you should be able to import `org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel like a total idiot now after realising what my mistake was. a huge thank you :)